# Structure Flask project so I can import my app in other files

Tags: python, flask

I built this app a few months ago on the flask server and it was working perfectly. I have uploaded all files into the right directories but I keep getting an Unhandled Exception saying there is No module named app.

Here is my structure:

```
 /static/
       (all static files)
 /templates/
       (all html files)
 myapp.py
```

In myapp.py:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, redirect, request, url_for

#index - Home page containing images for the trailer, discussion thread and cast
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    page_info = {
        'title':'Star Wars - Forums',
    }
    img1 = 'pan.jpg'
    img2 = 'trailerlink.jpg'
    img3 = 'trailerdiscussion.jpg'
    img4 = 'episode7cast.jpg'
    return render_template('index.html', info=page_info, imgone=img1, imgtwo=img2,imgthree=img3, imgfour=img4)
```

In my wsgi.py file:

```
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/myusername'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from myapp import app as application
```

And finally some of the errors in my error log:

```
File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__ app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 136, in import_error_application
raise e
ImportError: No module named app
```

It's probably just something small, it usually is, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: In myapp.py you're importing `app` from app.py. Where is app.py?

Comment: `from app import app` at the start of `myapp.py` is trying to import from a file called `app.py` that defines a variable called `app` (or a directory called `app` with a `__init__.py` that defines such a variable).  I don't see either of those in your file list above...?

Comment: Heh, you got there first, TeneCursum ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to refer to your project as a package.  You need to actually create a package called "app" if you want to do `from app import app`.

```
myproject/
    app/
        __init__.py  # contains `app` object
        views.py  # was called myapp.py, does `from app import app`
        static/
        templates/
    wsgi.py  # does `from app import app as application`
```

In this case the Flask `app` should be defined in `__init__.py` so that importing it from the `myapp` modules works.  Realistically, this naming scheme makes no sense, it looks like `myapp.py` should really be called `views.py`.